# Is the line with two origin a open equivalence relation?

Tags: general-topology

This is from Lee's smooth manifold problem 1.1:
[image]

I was wondering, is this equivalence relation an open equivalence as in the projection maps open sets to open sets? I tried a few cases and it seems to be true so far. If that is the case, then we get second-countable for free since the quotient topology of a second countable space is second countable.

Comment: Yes, the map $X\to X/\sim$ is open, but you'd have to prove that. It wouldn't be too hard, but not that much easier than proving it is second countable directly.

Answer (score 0):

Showing that the equivalence is open is the same as showing that the saturation $q^{-1}(q(U))$ of every open set $U$ is open, where $q$ denotes the quotient map. Let $r$ denote the homeomorphism of $X$ that takes $(x, y) \mapsto (x, - y)$ and let $U \subset X$ be open. Now note that the saturation of $U$ is given by
$$U \cup r(U \setminus\{(\pm 1, 0)\}).$$
Since $\{(\pm 1, 0)\}$ is closed, this is open.